# Detect browser when site is accessed

Tags: symfony

Is there anyway to detect browser version in symfony prior to loading any pages and then run a corresponding action?  I was thinking of using modernizr, but I was hoping to not have to rewrite all my views.

Basically what I was hoping I could accomplish is that before the framework attempts to match the url to a route it would first check to see if the user has a particular browser version and if not run another controller instead of the the controller defined in the route.

Comment: Did you see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/7yjJX5xA9yk)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what your suggesting is not a "best practice". I'm assuming you want to route a mobile request to a unique Action method in a Controller. You really shouldn't have a separate controller based client device. This is the job of the (V)view in MVC.

Modernizr is a client side solution with css,js but if youre using symfony, i would prefer server side and that requires the title of this question.. "Detecting browser on request".

While you can custom configure your app to detect the device(and its not to hard), there's also an easier option. Try this bundle. https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle . It does everything and allows for you to make both controller modifications or make twig aware of the browser so you can make smaller changes.